# getting all values in list without iterating through them

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

In my controller, I'm returning returning View with a list of products.

return View(ProductList)

In my view I want to get all the values of the product list **WITHOUT** iterating through them either with a for each loop or any other way.

I need to do this as I'm going to design each Product differently in the view and I can't use a for each loop

The first productId is available using **Model.Firstordefault().ProductId**. Similarly I can get productName, productDescription and so on.

But how can I get the second productId to nth productId in the list?

Thanks
Arnab
.

Answer (score 1):

That's a great candidate for a display template. In your strongly typed view simply:

```
@model IEnumerable<ProductViewModel>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Description</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @Html.DisplayForModel()
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and then define a display template which will automatically be rendered for each element of the collection (`~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/ProductViewModel.cshtml`):

```
@model ProductViewModel
<tr>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Id)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Name)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Description)</td>
</tr>
```

[Templated helpers](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2011/09/07/building-forms-for-deep-view-model-graphs-in-asp-net-mvc/) work by conventions and you never have to write any loops in your views.

Comment: thanks , but this will not work in my case as <tr></td> width etc will be same for all products which my design does not support,I think I have got a soln., testing that now.. Model.ElementAt(0).ProductId